# How to properly export keras_cv detection model for inference?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-cv

Using `keras_cv` (TF 2.12 on Linux) I have built and trained a model, similar to [official keras_cv documentation and examples](https://keras.io/guides/keras_cv/object_detection_keras_cv/).

```py
model = keras_cv.models.RetinaNet.from_preset(
    "resnet50_imagenet",
    num_classes=len(class_mapping),
    bounding_box_format="xywh")

    model.compile(...)
    model.fit(...)
```

This part is fine and model works as expected.

**Problem**

I am struggling to properly export model for inference.

I tried `model.export()` - it is failing. I tried with `tf.keras.export.ExportArchive`:

```py
export_archive = tf.keras.export.ExportArchive()
export_archive.track(model)
export_archive.add_endpoint(
    name="serve",
    fn=model.call,
    input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32)],
)
export_archive.write_out("path/to/location") ## throws exception
```

it is failing as well.

Every export method shows bunch of errors `INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'inputs'`.

The exception `export_archive.write_out()` is raising:

```
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

I guess this is due to some specifics of `keras_cv` model implementation. What is the proper way?

Comment: keras-cv is new, I think it's better to report to official repo.